# Add multiple UK Postcodes list to Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've tried loads of combinations and read through loads of articles on Stackoverflow but can't seem to get this to work..  Should be real easy but proving to be a right pain in the backside so just wondering if anyone can help..

simply trying to add some markers to a google map (& eventually directions) I have below code but all I get is blank screen.. If I strip out the markers code I do get the bare map so it is working in the page at least...  can anyone help..?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

                var geocoder;
                var map;
                function initialize() {
                  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                  var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 7
                  }
                  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
                  codeAddress();
                }

                function codeAddress() {
                  var address = ['SO21 3NE','Horsham'];
                  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                          map: map,
                          position: results[0].geometry.location
                      });
                    } else {
                      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
                    }
                  });
                }

                google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);//]]>
 </script>
```

this fixed it...

```
 var locations = ['SO21 3NE','Horsham','RG45 7EG'];
                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                var marker, i;
                var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 7
                  }
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

                for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

                geocoder.geocode( { 'address': locations[i]}, function(results, status) {
                    //alert(status);
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

                        //alert(results[0].geometry.location);
                        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: results[0].geometry.location,
                            map: map
                        }); 

                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() { infowindow.open(map, marker);});
                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() { infowindow.close();});

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert("some problem in geocode" + status);
        }
    }); 
}
                 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: geocoder expects a string for address if I'm not mistaken. What errors are thrown in browser console?

Answer (score 0):

I get a [javascript error with your code](http://jsfiddle.net/7xookft6/): `Uncaught InvalidValueError: in property address: not a string`

Your address property of the [GeocoderRequest](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#GeocoderRequest) is an array not a string.

```
function codeAddress() {
  var address = ['SO21 3NE','Horsham'];
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}
```

should be:

```
function codeAddress() {
  var address = 'SO21 3NE, Horsham';
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7xookft6/1/)

[example with 25 addresses](http://jsfiddle.net/5y888qvk/1/) from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19640055/multiple-markers-google-map-api-v3-from-array-of-addresses-and-avoid-over-query)

Comment: Thanks,, I should have explained better but the two entries in var address should be separate markers. There will be more as well.. So I need an array..

Comment: Last I checked "Horsham" is not a postal code. If your input is an array, you need code to process that array, send it in individual geocoder requests, handling the OVER_QUERY_LIMIT and other errors.  There are lots of duplicates of that question on SO.