# markerCluster not showing points

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I am trying to clustering some location on google map. I have tryied to merge the code from from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19640055/multiple-markers-google-map-api-v3-from-array-of-addresses-and-avoid-over-query) and the code from markercluster [examples](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/examples.html). But can't fix it. This is my code:

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 98%; height: 500px;border:2px solid #ccc;float:left"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js"></script>     
    <script>
function initialize() {
var elevator;
var myOptions = {
    zoom: 2,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
    mapTypeId: 'terrain'
    };
var map = new google.maps.Map($('#map_canvas')[0], myOptions);
var addresses = ['Argentina, Buenos Aires', 'Argentina, Cordoba, Cordoba Capital','Argentina, Cordoba, Rio Tercero'];
var markers = [];
for (var x = 0; x < addresses.length; x++) {
    $.getJSON('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+addresses[x]+'&sensor=false', null, function (data) {
        var p = data.results[0].geometry.location
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.lat, p.lng);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: latlng });
        markers.push(marker);
    });
    }
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
```

It is not a problem of jquery, because the example works very well if I don't try to use markerCluster. So I am doing something wrong with array passing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$.getJSON` runs asynchronously, `markers` will not be populated yet when you use it as argument for `MarkerClusterer`.

Use

```
markerCluster.addMarker(marker);
```

instead of

```
markers.push(marker);
```

Comment: I tryed definig `markerCluster` before the loop an then calling `markers.push(marker);` inside the loop, but does not work. other ideas?

Comment: please make yourself familiar with the term "asynchronously", it's not a matter of the position inside your code.

Comment: @emanuele - before the new loop declare   var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map);     Notice there is no marker option. Inside the loop do as the Doc says.  { ignore my edit about quotes, it was cut+paste error on my part }

Comment: @Dr.Molle @maurice Sorry I made a mistake writing the  comment above. What I would say is that I declared `var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map)` before the loop, then I called  `markerClusterer.addMarker(marker)` from inside the loop.

Comment: I solved calling `$.ajaxSetup({ async: false});` before loop. Thanx

Comment: `async:false` will block the page until the requests are finished(let's assume it may happen that the API didn't respond, do you want to have a freezed page?) Demo of the suggested modification: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/4z7L3d2q/