# How to display multiple location markers by address using google map api?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I don't want to display multiple markers using latitude and longitude, Only by addresses which are stored in mysql database. Latitude and Longitude are not stores in the table.

I have worked on it and was successful in displaying one marker, but my web app requires me to display multiple markers according to the location
Here's the code:

```
<?php include_once("dbcon.php") ;
?>
<html>
<?php
$search = $_POST['search'];
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM eventsTable WHERE eventLocation LIKE '%$search%'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
        $ename = $row["eventName"];
        $edate = $row["eventDate"];
        $edetail=$row["eventDetails"];
        $eloc = $row["eventLocation"];
        $ecity = $row["eventCity"];

        echo "<p> ".json_encode($eloc)."</p>"; echo json_encode($ecity);    }
?>

<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Geocoding Simple</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var geocoder;
  var map;
  var address = "<?php echo $eloc; ?>,<?php echo $ecity; ?>, PK";
  function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(30.51687, 69.40949);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 10,
      center: latlng,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
    navigationControl: true,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    if (geocoder) {
      geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
          map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
                { content: '<b>'+address+'</b>',
                  size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)
                });

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                map: map, 
                title:address
            }); 
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.open(map,marker);
            });

          } else {
            alert("No results found");
          }
        } else {
          alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
      });
    }
  }
</script>
</head>
<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" onload="initialize()">
 <div id="map_canvas" style= "right-padding=0px; width:50%; height:50%">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's not as hard as you think](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: How many "more markers"?  The geocoder will work for about 10 without hitting the query/rate limit.

Comment: almost about 40-50. :/

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to display multiple markers using latitude and longitude, Only by addresses which are stored in mysql database.

Unfortunately, Google Maps API requires latitude/longitude in order to add a marker to a map. You should consider using the [GeoLocation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation) to convert your addresses into coordinates first, then you can add the markers in the traditional fashion.

If this isn't possible, you can use AJAX to retrieve the latitude/longitude in a loop (like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19640055/multiple-markers-google-map-api-v3-from-array-of-addresses-and-avoid-over-query)), but you might hit the rate limit as mentioned in this question's comments.

Answer (score 0):

You are only outputting one address in your PHP code:

```
var address = "<?php echo $eloc; ?>,<?php echo $ecity; ?>, PK";
```

You need to  create an array of addresses and process that array.

[Proof of issues with array of more than 11 addresses](http://jsfiddle.net/bsohgtfr/)

See [OVER_QUERY_LIMIT in Google Maps API v3: How do I pause/delay in Javascript to slow it down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792916/over-query-limit-in-google-maps-api-v3-how-do-i-pause-delay-in-javascript-to-sl) (Andrew Leach's answer) for a way to deal with the OVER_QUERY_LIMIT.