# Google Maps geocoding an array on address not working properly - only one marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

I am trying to have a map with multiple markers on it.

If I do it with coordinates, it works fine. The problem is I have not the coordinates of all the places. What I certainly have is the address.

So I opted for the geocoding. It works fine with only one marker, but I don't understand why, it doesn't loop through the array of locations.

Here is my code:

```
    var locations = [

    ['B&B Al Centro Storico', 41.203517, 16.600466, 2,'Via Samuelli 83','Barletta'],
    ['B&B Cortile Fondo Noce', 41.276672, 16.417772, 3,'Via Fondo Noce 29','Bisceglie']
    ];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mappa'), {
        zoom: 9,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.239162, 16.500301),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        scrollwheel: false,
        disableDefaultUI: true
    });


    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();




    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;
    var infoWindowContent = [];


    function setPin(indirizzo,mappa)
    {
        geocoder.geocode({'address':  indirizzo}, function(results, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: mappa,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location
                });
                }                       
        });                 
    }


    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {


        // geocoder.geocode({'address':  locations[i][4] + ', ' + locations[i][5]}, function(results, status) {
            // if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                // marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    // map: map,
                    // position: results[0].geometry.location
                // });
                // }                        
        // });          


        setPin(locations[i][4] + ' ' + locations[i][5],map);


        // marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            // position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            // map: map 
        // });

        infoWindowContent[i] = '<b>'+locations[i][0]+'</b>';                    


        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infowindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i]);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));
    }
```

You can see the commented out lines of the lat,long version that works as expected.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The code you posted doesn't work at all.

Comment: Here are two good answers to your question.  Netbrain's answer sends all the requests at once; the acceptep answer (agnes) has a counter; when request 0 is ready, it increases the counter and sends the next request... The first answer is easier; the second answer is better.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19640055/multiple-markers-google-map-api-v3-from-array-of-addresses-and-avoid-over-query

Comment: If you have the coordinates, why are you using the geocoder?

Comment: @geocodezip I have NOT the coordinates, as I say in my post :)

Comment: @EmmanuelDelay Thanks a lot! I have adjusted my script according the Netbrain solution. The error was that I called the eventlistner on the marker OUTSIDE the check on the GeocoderStatus AND that marker wasn't an array. I changed those and now it works. The only thing remaining is that the pins do not open the infowindow. I will update my answer with my solutions

Comment: @MrUpsidown Thanks for your comment. I don't understand the downvote. The script doesn't work on jsfiddle. It works as described (with its own errors), on a simple html page. I am preparing a html file so you all can check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the code that depends on the marker inside the `setPin` function.

```
function setPin(indirizzo, i, mappa) {
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': indirizzo
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: mappa,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
          infoWindowContent[i] = '<b>' + locations[i][0] + '</b>';

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i]);
      infowindow.open(mappa, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
    } else alert("geocode failed:"+indirizzo+" status="+status)
  });
}
```

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var locations = [

    ['B&B Al Centro Storico', 41.203517, 16.600466, 2, 'Via Samuelli 83', 'Barletta'],
    ['B&B Cortile Fondo Noce', 41.276672, 16.417772, 3, 'Via Fondo Noce 29', 'Bisceglie']
  ];

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mappa'), {
    zoom: 9,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.239162, 16.500301),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    scrollwheel: false,
    disableDefaultUI: true
  });

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var marker, i;
  var infoWindowContent = [];

  function setPin(indirizzo, i, mappa) {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({
      'address': indirizzo
    }, function(results, status) {
      if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: mappa,
          position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
        infoWindowContent[i] = '<b>' + locations[i][0] + '</b>';

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
          return function() {
            infowindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i]);
            infowindow.open(mappa, marker);
          }
        })(marker, i));
      } else alert("geocode failed:" + indirizzo + " status=" + status)
    });
  }

  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    setPin(locations[i][4] + ' ' + locations[i][5], i, map);
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#mappa {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="mappa"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I temporarily solved by using only the venues which I had the coordinates of. You solution allows me to use all the venues using the geocode. Thanks again.